# I'm tring to get $handle use frida,but it return undefined

Tags: frida

this is my code:

```
 Java.perform(function(){
    var dexclassLoader = Java.use("dalvik.system.DexClassLoader");
    var ClassUse = Java.use("java.lang.Class");

    dexclassLoader.loadClass.overload('java.lang.String').implementation = function(name){
        var result = this.loadClass(name,false);
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.$handle);
        send(result);
        return result;
    }
});
```

this is result:

```
class android.widget.LinearLayout
undefined
[*] <instance: java.lang.Class>
```

I can't get JSON object of the class like this:

```
class cn.chaitin.geektan.crackme.MainActivityPatch
[*] {'$handle': '0x1d2006ee', '$weakRef': 693}
```

Comment: Where did you got the sample output from? May be it was created by on older version on Frida.

Comment: I'm using frida 12.8.19 and android 8.1.0 on pixel2